# Java cant run jar with processbuilder

Tags: java

Heres my code please help! I'm making a launcher for my game. I want to be able to launch the game from the launcher but it dosent work.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.jar","C:/Users/Marcus/Documents/");
            try {
                pb.directory(new File("C:\\"));
                Process p = pb.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test.jar" (in directory "C:\"): CreateProcess error=2, Cant find the file  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error as well as describe how you are running this?  The information will be helpful in determining what is happening.

Comment: Add the error output...

Comment: Don't embed your answer in your question.  If you've got this answered, answer your own question below.

Answer (score 0):

Your test.jar is relative that's why i cannot find the it.
You have to specify the path to test.jar

Then you should check if your jar is executable. If not you will need to add java to the list of arguments when creating the ProcessBuilder.